# sar service has stopped collecting data

Tags: sar

We had `sar` working on our Ubuntu server, but did some work on the server and now it's stopped logging to the day's logfile.

```
sar -b 5 5
```

This indicates that `sar` is alive, and monitoring data, but

```
ubuntu@testing:/var/log/sysstat$ sar
```

outputs:

```
Linux 5.4.0-1063-azure (server)     02/22/22    _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

10:22:05     LINUX RESTART  (4 CPU)

10:22:46     LINUX RESTART  (4 CPU)

10:24:25     LINUX RESTART  (4 CPU)

16:34:04     LINUX RESTART  (4 CPU)
```

The cron and the `sysstat` config have not changed.

```
*/1 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

Why isn't stats data getting added to the log?

Answer (score 7):

Comparing 2 installations, one is Debian 11 that was upgraded from Debian 10, and the other is a fresh Debian 11, both **using systemd**:

- on Debian 10 then 11, I already have `sysstat-collect` and `sysstat-summary` enabled
- on fresh Debian 11, I don't

So, if you're using **systemd**, you should reconfigure `sysstat` that will run through systemd and not through crontab:

```
dpkg-reconfigure sysstat
```

Select "Yes".

Editing `/etc/default/sysstat` directly (as I did until now) is a mistake: it doesn't update systemd files.

Note that you'll see `/etc/default/sysstat` updated to `ENABLED="true"`, but the cron won't run anymore (systemd will trigger it as expected).

You can check everything is fine using:

```
systemctl status sysstat-collect.timer
systemctl status sysstat-summary.timer
```

which should reply with «Active: active (waiting)»

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case (Debian 11), one solution was changing `debian-sa1` to `sa1` in the `cron` file since the `debian-sa1` will be exited when the system is shipped with being `systemd` enable.

After applying this hack, the `cron` config file of `sysstat` would be like this (`/etc/cron.d/sysstat`):

```
...
*/1 * * * * root command -v sa1 > /dev/null && sa1 1 1
...
```

---

**EDIT**:

As [Yvan](https://serverfault.com/users/114520/yvan) explained, to run `sysstat` by `systemd` instead of `cron`, we can start `sysstat-collect.timer` and `sysstat-summary.timer` timers manually, in case they are inactive:

```
systemctl start sysstat sysstat-collect.timer sysstat-summary.timer
```

And also enable them to be automatically started by system boot-up:

```
systemctl enable sysstat sysstat-collect.timer sysstat-summary.timer
```

Finally and after explaining these hacks, maybe the best solution, in this case, is to reconfigure `sysstat` to be run with `systemd` instead of `cron`, which is greatly described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1115810/964864) by Yvan.

Comment: Looking at the debian-sa1 script, it seems that it's returning nothing if `systemd` is enabled. So you may run it through `systemd` and not through cron anymore.

Comment: @Yvan You are completely right about the `debian-sa1` script, although it was strangely the default state of the delivered VPS. It seems I could have started two related service timers (`sysstat-collect.timer` and `sysstat-summary.timer`) manually, while they were supposed to be triggered by starting the `sysstat` service (according to the `sysstat.service` code).
I will add more details to this answer to cover this as an alternative solution.

Comment: As the follow-up to the previous comment, the reason that `sysstat-collect.timer` and `sysstat-summary.timer` have not been triggered is the fact that `systemd` runs the `[install]` section of a service (in this case, `sysstat`) only if we make the service `enable`, and in this case, the mentioned services are triggered there. So, we could only enable `sysstat`.

Comment: I think that `dpkg-reconfigure sysstat` does exactly that: enabling the service, which in turns enables both timers. So it seems that one way or the other is fine. But editing `/etc/` or cron files is wrong. I've learned it the hard way. Same as `myservice.service.d/override.conf` for systemd, which is very powerful.

Comment: I agree with you. Editing the `sysstat` cron file is not neat and only is a hack around. So, `dpkg-reconfigure sysstat` seems to be the best approach to resolve this problem.